# How to check hotlinking on my website

Tags: php, html, image, hyperlink

I've got a website with images, and their links are often on other website. How could I do to understand if I can delete an image or not? Like checking where the links are, or if somebody sees the image from other websites.

I hope you can understand my ask.

Thanks

Comment: Depending on which web-server you use to serve the images, they will log each access. It's not perfect, but for most cases the logged referer (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) will tell you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check hotlinking you need to have the HTTP_REFERER value of the HTTP query that asks for your image. It is not a reliable way because several reasons might lead to it not being populated at all, even in a hotlinked request ("Personal firewall" solutions, proxies, and so on).

Your best option would be to include referer in the logs, in the case of Apache which is often used then see "Combined Log format"

```
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html
```

and then analyze the logs with a suitable tool (e.g. AWstats).

To check for *broken* hotlinks, you can check the `ErrorLog`; if someone no longer finds an image, that will leave traces in the log.

**If you have no access to the logs** (or to the configuration), but you have access to `.htaccess`, you could use `mod_rewrite`.

You do this by redirecting internally (the user sees nothing) links such as

```
 http://www.yoursite.com/images/myimage.jpg
```

to a server side script such as

```
 http://www.yoursite.com/images/index.php?image=myimage.jpg
```

Now the user *thinks* he's still requesting `myimage`, but he's actually invoking the script. The script might then store last access time in the database, or note some other way that the image is in use: for example in PHP one could use the function `touch()` to update file modification time. At that point you can easily find out which files have been recently accessed and which weren't.

All these methods are prone to error (for example, someone might be hotlinking and accessing your image through a proxy. The proxy has a long retention time and does not check upstream even if it would be wise. You remove the image, nothing happens - until a week later when the proxy synchs and you see an access at last; and a failed one at that), but it's the best you can do.

Comment: Thank you very much for you exhaustive answer! I was already going through that way, but I don't understand how to redirect/show the image after having executed my php file. Header() seems to cause a infinite loop...

Comment: No, you have to serve the image directly: `Header('content-type: image/jpeg'); readfile(path_to_real_image); exit();`. In the interest of cache-friendliness and bandwidth, you should also send Content-Length, Last-Modified and ETag headers, and possibly handle If-Modified-Since and If-None-Match requests.

Answer (score 2):

You can never be sure if an image is not linked to from anywhere or if noone happens to access it. There might be a page that hotlinks the image but just doesn't get any traffic.

Examining your web server access logs would tell you *if* an image is being used and how frequently; [setting up referer logs](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/logging-external-referers-with-apache/) would help you determine *where* an image is used. With this data in hand you can consider your next move from a better standpoint.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But, how about if I don't have access to my virtual host configuration??

Comment: `.htaccess` can offer similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

with Apache, you can check to prevent `hotlinking` (that's how it's call when someone link to your image from another website).

Here's an answer: http://altlab.com/htaccess_tutorial.html

And here's a tool to generate your `.htaccess` http://www.htaccesstools.com/hotlink-protection/

But there's plenty more on google

Comment: Hi Simon, thank you! But I want to allow hotlinking, I just want to know if an image is hotlinked or not.